# Dynamic google javascripts loading failing

Tags: javascript, performance, dynamic, google-visualization

I have several listeners on modals that look like this:

```
$('#modaledithistory').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    loadjscssfile("js/editable_table.js", "js", function(){ setHistory(true); });
});
```

The function being called is:

```
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype, callback){
    if (filesadded.indexOf("["+filename+"]")==-1){
        if (filetype=="js"){ 
            var fileref=document.createElement('script');
            fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
            fileref.setAttribute("src", filename);
            
            fileref.onreadystatechange = callback;
            fileref.onload = callback;  
        }

        if (typeof fileref!="undefined"){
            // Fire the loading
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
            console.log("added to html: " + filename);
        }
        
        filesadded+="["+filename+"]";
    } else {
        window[callback]();
        console.log("already loaded: " + filename);
    }
    console.log(callback);
}
```

This works just fine and as expected. 
The problem happens with this listener:

```
$('#modalreporting').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    loadjscssfile("https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js", "js", null);
    loadjscssfile("js/graphs.js", "js", function(){ initGraphs(); drawGraphs(); mobileRotateScreen(true); 
} );
```

The console errors I get from this don't make any sense considering the code with the callback actually states to wait until the file is completely loaded BEFORE executing code.
Errors:

```
graphs.js:20 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
    at graphs.js:20
graphs.js:313 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DataTable' of undefined
    at drawGaugegraph (graphs.js:313)
    at drawGraphs (graphs.js:49)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onreadystatechange (javascript.js:1030)
```

The lines generating the errors:

```
// line 20
google.charts.load('current', {
    packages: ['corechart']
});

// line 313
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(),
        max = 0;
```

So what the console is saying is that the object 'google' doesn't exist.
The file however, should be loaded. I went through it and there isn't even a google object created in there.
When placing the script element directly in the html it works, but for performance reasons I'd rather not do that.

Can anyone help me make sense of this?
Thx!

EDIT:
I noticed the `window[callback]();` also isn't working as it should be.
On doing that line I get `javascript.js:1011 Uncaught TypeError: window[callback] is not a function`.

Answer (score 1):

first, try waiting for the google charts script to load, before loading the next script...

```
$('#modalreporting').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    loadjscssfile("https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js", "js", function () {
      loadjscssfile("js/graphs.js", "js", function() {
        initGraphs();
        drawGraphs(); 
        mobileRotateScreen(true);
      });
    });
});
```

next, you need to wait for google's `load` statement to finish,
before using the `google.visualization` namespace...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(),
  max = 0;
  ...
});
```

Comment: hope this helps, as for `window[callback]` -- where do you set the callback? --> `window[callback] = someCallback;`

Comment: `window[callback]();` should have been `callback();`. Dunno why I even tried something I don't understand :p

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: in order to be able to make a long comment and add formatting I need to post an answer.

I adapted it a bit, cause the 3 functions after the loading of the JS file actually call the datatable etc and need to be re-executable (hence `window[callback]();` in loadjscssfile).

```
$('#modalreporting').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    loadjscssfile("https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js", "js", function () {
      loadjscssfile("js/graphs.js", "js", function() {
        console.log("loaded graphs2");
        
        initGoogleLibraries("googleCharts").then(function () {
            initGraphs();
            drawGraphs(); 
            mobileRotateScreen(true);
        });
      });
    });
});
```

graphs.js

```
function initGoogleLibraries(googleLib) {
    if (filesadded.indexOf("["+googleLib+"]")==-1){
        google.charts.load('current', {
            packages: ['corechart','gauge']
        }).then(function () {
            filesadded+="["+googleLib+"]";
            console.log("loaded google Lib");
        });
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

The then is giving issues.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined at HTMLScriptElement.onreadystatechange
```

Basically the logic behind it should be:

1. Click modal
2. Load JS files
3. When JS loaded, load the google 'corechart' and 'gauge' libraries
4. When libraries loaded execute initGraphs(), drawGraphs() and mobileRotateScreen(true)
5. When modal is closed and clicked again only initGraphs(), drawGraphs() and mobileRotateScreen(true) should be executed again (because loading the js all over again would be even less performant than it was before.